# Css :not pseudo class is not taking effect

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I want to use the `:not` pseudo class as an exception where the css should apply to everything except any element with a certain class including all its children elements.

But in my example, the `:not` selector is affecting everything, but only should affect the class inside the `:not` selector. I'm using chrome browser.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/galivan/4gwyk5eu/)

**SCSS**:

```
.ql-editor :not(.not-ql-editor){

  ul > li {
      background:blue;
  }

}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="ql-editor">

   <ul>
        <li>hello</li>
        <li>hello</li>
        <li>hello</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="not-ql-editor">
      <ul>
        <li>hello</li>
        <li>hello</li>
        <li>hello</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would have expected the top `<ul><li>` to have blue background, while the lower `<ul><li>` would not have a background because it has the `.not-ql-editor` class, but something seems wrong since no `li` elements get the background.

**Update**:
After the answer by Johannes I learned that the upper `ul` needs to be wrapped inside some element because the  `:not(.not-ql-editor)` represents an element even if it doesn't match the selector.
But then I noticed that the `"not-ql-editor`" element has to be directly underneath the `"ql-editor"` element. My aim was to target a class at any level beneath "`ql-editor`".

Normally when you but a space between two selectors, the second selector should target elements at any level beneath the first one. Is this not the case with the :not selector?

**update2**:

Here is a modified version of the fiddle:
[fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/galivan/4gwyk5eu/19/)

If the html looks like this (with the same css):

```
<div class="ql-editor"> 
  <div>
    <div class="not-ql-editor">
        <ul>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The li's become blue. Despite the css: `.ql-editor :not(.not-ql-editor)`

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that the first list is on a different "descendant level" than the second list: Your CSS selector is valid only for `li` elements inside a `ul` which is *child* of an element that does not have the `.not-ql-editor` which again is child of an element that has the `.ql-editor` class.

For this to work you need another `div` (or other)  wrapper around your first `ul`:

```css
.ql-editor :not(.not-ql-editor) ul>li {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="ql-editor">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>hello></li>
      <li>hello</li>
      <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="not-ql-editor">
    <ul>
      <li>hello</li>
      <li>hello</li>
      <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

ADDITION after comments and edit of question:

In the first code example you posted, your `ul` elements were on different descendant levels from the `.ql-editor` DIV element: The first `ul` was a directchild, the second one a grandchild, with the `.not-ql-editor` DIV as a wrapper between `.ql-editor` and the `ul`. My answer was directed at this situation, and it worked.

In the second code example you posted, you added another level: A DIV without any class in between the `.ql-editor` DIV and the `.not-ql-editor` DIV. This changes things. In the fiddle you added, the `.not-ql-editor` DIV is the direct parent of the `ul`. So you need to use *that* relationship to define a CSS rule that only applies if the `ul` is  a *direct* child of a DIV that does *not*  have the  `.not-ql-editor` class.

in plain CSS that rule would be as follows:

```
.ql-editor *:not(.not-ql-editor) > ul > li {
      background: blue;
}
```

Here's your second code example combined with that CSS rule in a snippet, The background does * not*  become blue:

```css
.ql-editor *:not(.not-ql-editor) > ul > li {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="ql-editor">
  <div>
    <div class="not-ql-editor">
      <ul>
        <li>hello</li>
        <li>hello</li>
        <li>hello</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's your second fiddle with this CSS applied as SCSS: https://jsfiddle.net/e7d0h4yc/

Comment: So if I understood it, the :not(.not-ql-editor) represents some element even if it there is no element of the target class, I didn't knew. Thanks!

Comment: yes, it's the same as if you wrote `*:not(.not-ql-editor)`

Comment: I just noticed a problem though - if I wrap the lower div with class "not-ql-editor" inside a div,then the .not-gl-editor will get the blue background. I would like the :not(.not-ql-editor) to match a selector at any level under the ".ql-editor" . It seems that the current behaviour is equivalent to ".ql-editor > :not(.not-ql-editor)"

Comment: I don't understand completely what you mean (an example would be good), but you could apply the `:not(.not-ql-editor)` class directly to the `ul`, not to its wrapping `div`. So the selector would be `.ql-editor ul:not(.not-ql-editor) > li`. You could even drop the `ul` and make it `.ql-editor :not(.not-ql-editor) > li`. Since the `ul` completely fills its wrapper, there should be no difference to the outcome of my example, and you wouldn't depend on extra wrappers.

Comment: I think you misunderstood something, or you have another special sitution that doesn't correspond to your example or my answer. But your statement/assumption, that "`.ql-editor :not(.not-ql-editor)`  is equivalent to `.ql-editor > :not(.not-ql-editor)` " is not correct. You'd need to add another code example which reproduces the problem to your question to show what you really mean.

Comment: I have updated the question with another fiddle where the li's become blue when I wrap the `.not-ql-editor` in another div. That shouldn't happen if this: `.ql-editor :not(.not-ql-editor)` is not equivalent to: `.ql-editor > :not(.not-ql-editor)` ?

Comment: Note the addition to my answer

Comment: I'm looking for a flexible way to exclude everything that's underneath the "not" rule, regardless of hierarchy or what type of elements it has , it should not only apply to one specific example.So the blue background `ul li` shouldn't apply if they have a parent element at any level above it with `:not(.not-ql-editor)` . But maybe it isn't possible to use it in that way.

Comment: Well, that won't be possible: If there are additional levels between the `ul` and the container, there will *always*  be an element in between to which `:not(.not-ql-editor)` will apply. So the solution is basically what I already wrote in my second comment above: you should apply the `.not-ql-editor` class directly to the `ul`, not to its wrapping div. That way you achieve the desired filtering using `*:not(.not-ql-editor) > li` or `ul:not(.not-ql-editor) > li` alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the original HTML you had. Since the top `ul` element and the `div.not-ql-editor` element are siblings, you can just attach the `not` rule to a wildcard element, and instead of targeting `ul > li` just target `li`

```css
.ql-editor>*:not(.not-ql-editor) li {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="ql-editor">
  <ul>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>hello</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="not-ql-editor">
    <ul>
      <li>hello</li>
      <li>hello</li>
      <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.ql-editor :not(.not-ql-editor){

  ul > li {
      background:blue;
  }

}
```

Correct this to remove the space between ql-editor and :not

```
.ql-editor div :not(.not-ql-editor){

      background:blue;

}
```